# (2004 Lincoln Navigator) How do I set up these screens in the back?

Tags: electrical, ford, lincoln, navigator

They were like this when we bought it. I tried putting a DVD in it and it wouldn’t turn on at all. It came with extra cables and extra connectors.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

All that loose wiring suggests that the cabling or the electronics (or both) have been modified or changed, and aren't stock.

In order to get things working, I think you'll have to go to a car audio/video store (where equipment like this is sold and installed) and get them to figure out what components are in the vehicle now, and how those components are connected.